# Code works on Android studio emulator but not on android mobiles

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-emulator

I wrote a simple login program, tested it on Android Studio Emulator and it worked fine.
Then I tried to use my mobile to debug it, and it crashed as soon as the send button was pressed.
This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginFrag.PinManager {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LoginFrag fragment = new LoginFrag();
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_frame_layout, fragment)
                    .commit();
}
@Override
public void checkPin(int i) {
    int pin = i;
    if (pin!=123){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        loadMenu(); 
    }

}


public class LoginFrag extends Fragment {

private Button button;
private EditText editText;
PinManager pinActivity;

public interface PinManager{
    public void checkPin(int i);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        pinActivity = (PinManager) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
    }
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_frag, container, false);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pin);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pinReader(v);
                }
            }
    );
    return view;
}
public void pinReader(View v){
    pinActivity.checkPin(Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString()));
    editText.setText("");
    }
}
```

The error is the following:

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41781e48)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.max.passwordmanager, PID: 13259
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.example.max.passwordmanager.LoginFrag.pinReader(LoginFrag.java:57)
                  at com.example.max.passwordmanager.LoginFrag$1.onClick(LoginFrag.java:47)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4461)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18523)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13259 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

I ran the code on two mobiles, one with android 4.4.2 the other with android 5.0.2, both same crash as soon as you click the button to send the pin.

Comment: Error shows that you got null value for that edittext. Best practice to use fragment is, you should inflater layout in OncreateView method. But findViewbyid and other click listener should be in OnViewCreated() method

Comment: I tried moving the part of code in the onViewCreated but nothing changed

Comment: Try to add Log method inside pinReader() for edittext Value. And give log error

Comment: I have never used Log before, do you mean to pass editText as the string in Log? In that case the number I got is the same I inputed. The error log is the same

Comment: Add this line in starting of pinReader();                    Log.e("EdtValue", " "+edittext.getText().toString());     and run app, then post log here

Comment: **11-07 19:28:00.117 22898-22898/com.example.max.passwordmanager E/EdtValue:  252       **     
I guess only the filtered part, right?

Comment: This means edittext ia not null. Then your Listener Interface is giving null pointer. I think it not initialized in fragment.

Comment: @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        pinActivity=null;
        super.onDetach();
    }
}

Comment: Nothing as changed using onDetach()

Comment: I am using same thing in my code and it is working. Except i create new Interface outer of activity. Have to try to remove pinReader method and directly put checkPin inside onClick. Make sure you use try catch block. Then run your app and observe logcat.